# Why maven is not showing correct OS version

Tags: windows, maven-3

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

And I installed Maven on my machine. When I checked the version of Maven by running `mvn --version` it showed Windows 8.1.
I installed maven on windows 10 only.

What is happening here? Why is Maven unable to get current OS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows OS reports version codes that have to be translated to the name of a particular Windows release given by Microsoft's marketing team.  For example, it will return 6.0 for Windows Vista and 6.3 for Windows 8.1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

The API does indeed return 10.0 for Windows 10, but Maven's code to translate the version number to the marketing name likely did not expect such consistency.  Maven will likely be updated at some point in the future to correctly display Windows 10.

Comment: I hope _Windows_ will likely be updated at some point in the future to correctly display "Windows 10". ;-)

Comment: Windows has always returned a version number.  I agree, it would be nice if the API also returned the common name.  That has caused quite some problems for software over the years that wants to correctly display the OS name.

Comment: @venkatesh As a proof which demonstrates Eric J.'s response, you could open a shell and execute "ver".

Comment: Sad that not even the `ver` command can display the common/marketing name of your Windows version in addition to the version code :-)

Comment: @LittleSanti yes I executed the command 'ver' in command prompt but it displayed as "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]"

Comment: @EricJ. thanks alot Eric for replying, hope what you said could be the reason.

Comment: @venkatesh: That's because Windows 10 happens to match up to the major version number returned.  If you do this on Windows 8.1 you get `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]`